# Ajax отправка данных методом POST из калькулятора

Tags: ajax, post, калькулятор

**Здравствуйте!**

Калькулятор **не вставляет результаты рассчета на страницу**, в чем дело никак не пойму. Вроде переменным name присвоил... **Подскажите друзья - что не так?**

**Есть скрипт для вставки результатов рассчёта:**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$('.sample2').click( function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'post_calc.php',
          data: $("#order_form").serialize(),
          success: function(data){
            $('.results').html(data);
          }
        });

    });
</script>
```

**Вот калькулятор:**

```
<form class='form-horizontal' method='post' id='order_form'>
  <div class='control-group'>
    <label class='control-label'>Материал потолка:<span class='attention' title='Поле, обязательное к заполнению'>*</span></label>
    <div class='controls' style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <div class='btn-group' data-toggle='buttons-radio'>
    <input type="hidden" id="material" name="material" value="ПВХ">
  <button type='button' id='5' name="pvh" class='btn active btn-success' 
  onClick="
  document.getElementById('5').className = 'btn active btn-success';
  document.getElementById('515').className = 'btn';
  document.getElementById('pvh').style.display='inline-block';document.getElementById('tkan').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('fact').style.display='inline-block'; document.getElementById('fact').style.display='inline-block'; 
  document.getElementById('facttkan').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('material').value = 'ПВХ';
  document.getElementById('colors_r').style.display='inline-block';
  ">ПВХ</button>
  <button type='button' id='515' name="tkan" class='btn' 
  onClick="
  document.getElementById('5').className = 'btn';
  document.getElementById('515').className = 'btn active btn-success';
  document.getElementById('tkan').style.display='inline-block';document.getElementById('pvh').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('fact').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('facttkan').style.display='inline-block';
  document.getElementById('material').value = 'Ткань';
  document.getElementById('colors_r').style.display='none';
  ">Тканевый</button>
</div>
 </div>
  </div>

  <div class='control-group' id="fact">
    <label class='control-label'>Фактура потолка:<span class='attention' title='Поле, обязательное к заполнению'>*</span></label>
    <div class='controls' style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <div class='btn-group' data-toggle='buttons-radio'>
    <input type="hidden" id="factura" name="factura" value="Глянцевый">
  <button type='button' id='gl' class='btn active btn-success' 
  onClick="
  document.getElementById('gl').className = 'btn active btn-success';
  document.getElementById('mat').className = 'btn';
  document.getElementById('sat').className = 'btn';
  document.getElementById('pvh').style.display='inline-block';document.getElementById('tkan').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('factura').value = 'Глянцевый';
  ">Глянцевый</button>
  <button type='button' id='mat' name='mat' class='btn' 
  onClick="
  document.getElementById('gl').className = 'btn';
  document.getElementById('sat').className = 'btn';
  document.getElementById('mat').className = 'btn active btn-success';
  document.getElementById('tkan').style.display='inline-block';document.getElementById('pvh').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('factura').value = 'Матовый';
  ">Матовый</button>
  <button type='button' id='sat' name='sat' class='btn' 
  onClick="
  document.getElementById('gl').className = 'btn';
  document.getElementById('sat').className = 'btn active btn-success';
  document.getElementById('mat').className = 'btn';
  document.getElementById('tkan').style.display='inline-block';document.getElementById('pvh').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('factura').value = 'Сатин';
  ">Сатин</button>
</div>
 </div>
  </div>

  <div class='control-group' id="facttkan" style="display:none;">
    <label class='control-label'>Фактура полотна:<span class='attention' title='Поле, обязательное к заполнению'>*</span></label>
                <div class='controls' style="margin-top: 10px;">
<select id="pvh" name="pvh">
  <option>pvh</option>
</select>
<select id="tkan" name="tkan" style="display:none;">
  <option>Ткань1</option>
  <option>Ткань2</option>
  <option>Ткань3</option>
  <option>Ткань4</option>
  <option>Ткань5</option>
</select><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" style="border-bottom: 1px dashed;">Галерея полотен</a></span></div>
            </div>

  <div class='control-group' id="colors_r" style="display:inline-block;">
  <input type='hidden' id='color' name='color' value='Белый'>
    <label class='control-label'>Цвет потолка:<span class='attention' title='Поле, обязательное к заполнению'>*</span></label>
    <div class='controls' style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <div class='btn-group' data-toggle='buttons-radio'>
  <button type='button' id='white' name='white' class='btn active btn-success' 
  onClick="
  document.getElementById('white').className = 'btn active btn-success';
  document.getElementById('rgb').className = 'btn';document.getElementById('colorarea').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('color').value = 'Белый';
  ">Белый</button>
  <button type='button' id='rgb' class='btn' 
  onClick="
  document.getElementById('white').className = 'btn';
  document.getElementById('rgb').className = 'btn active btn-success';
  document.getElementById('colorarea').style.display='inline-block';
  document.getElementById('color').value = '';
  "><i class="icon-screenshot"></i> Выбрать цвет</button>
<div id="colorarea" style="display:none;"><input id="your_input" type="text" name="colors" style=" visibility:hidden; width:2px;" />
<script type="text/javascript"> $("#your_input").modcoder_excolor({
        }); </script></div>
</div>
 </div>
  </div>

  <div class='control-group'>
    <label class='control-label'>
    Размеры помещения:<br>
    (Длина х Ширина)
    </label>
    <div class='controls'>
      <input type="text" id='dlin' name="dlin" onkeyup='Rech()' value="1" style="width: 30px;" /> х 
      <input type="text" id='shir' name="shir" onkeyup='Rech()' value="1" style="width: 30px;" /> м
      <input type="hidden" id="p_ploshad" name="ploshad">
      <input type="hidden" id="p_dlin" name="p_dlin">
      <input type="hidden" id="p_shir" name="p_shir">
      <span style="margin-left:50px;">Площадь потолка:<span id='ploshad'>0</span> м<sup>2</sup></span> 
    </div>
            </div>

  <div class='control-group'>
    <label class='control-label'>
    Конструкция под люстру:</label>
    <div class='controls'>
      <input name="lustr" type="checkbox" value="">
          </div>
  </div>

       <div class='control-group'>
    <label class='control-label'>Конструкция под светильники:</label>
    <div class='controls'><input name="svetiln" type="checkbox" value="" onChange="
  document.getElementById('kolsvet').style.display='inline-block';
  "><span style="margin-left:50px; display:none;" id="kolsvet">Количество светильников:<input type="number" name='k_svetiln' value="" style="width: 30px; margin-left:10px;"/> шт.</span>
          </div>
  </div>

  <div class='control-group'>
    <label class='control-label'>
    Окантовка трубы:</label>
    <div class='controls'>
      <input type="number" name='trub' value="" style="width: 30px;"/> шт.
      <span style="margin-left:50px;">Декоративная лента:<input type="number" name='lent' value="" style="width: 30px; margin-left:10px;"/> м
          </div>
  </div>

  <div class='control-group'>
    <div class='controls'>
      <input type="hidden" name="id" />
      <button class='btn btn-success sample2' type='submit' id='sample2'>Рассчитать стоимость</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="results">Ждем результатов рассчёта...</div>
```

Comment: JS подключен до или после формы?

Если до, оберните ваш JS в такую конструкцию:

    $(function() {
        // Ваш код
    })

Comment: @LinnTroll JS подключен после формы!

Comment: еще добавте в самый конец функции click

    return false;

Иначе вы просто отправите форму.